# Does Swarm incorporate the Git protocol like IPFS does?

Tags: ipfs, swarm

Does Swarm use Git for updating documents, like IPFS does, or does it use something else? I couldn't figure this out from reading any of the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

Swarm doesn't update documents. An upload produces a specific hash, which is the address of the content.

When you upload a new version, you get a different hash, which becomes the new address of your latest version. This means you get versioning for free.

If you upload a directory, you can change the contents of the directory by issuing a POST to the hash of the upload. This also produces a new hash, which corresponds to the latest version of your directory - again keeping the old version with the old hash.

Comment: That actually sounds kind of similar to IPFS's Git-based versioning.

Comment: aaah you may know IPFS better than I do :)

Answer (score 0):

(I don't know the answer to your actual question, but the below may be of some use.)

A while back there was a project called [Mango](https://github.com/axic/mango) that (claimed it) provided the abstraction layer for plugging Git into any of the P2P content-addressable networks, including Swarm. So slightly different, in that we're not talking about incorporating Git directly.

I'm unsure of the current state of the project. More [here](https://medium.com/@alexberegszaszi/mango-git-completely-decentralised-7aef8bcbcfe6).